# PyUSB ask for device Status

Tags: python-2.7, libusb, pyusb

I'm trying to write a script for barcode printers.

Here is my Code:

```
def printLabel(barcode, qty, articlenr=''):
    dev = findPrinter()
    dev.write("")
    return True

if __name__ =="__main__":

    for i in range(2):
        try:
            # Everything works fine, the for loop breaks
            printLabel('01234567890123','1', 'Hello World')
            break
        except usb.core.USBError as error:
            if   "Resource busy" in unicode(error):
                # Printer is doing something, wait 3 seconds, try again
                time.sleep(3)
                print 'Retrying after error:"Resource busy"\n' + str(error)
                printLabel('01234567890123','1', 'Hello World')
            elif "Operation Timeout" in unicode(error):
                # Printer is not responding
                print 'ERROR! Check Paper!\n' + str(error)
            else:
                print 'Unknown error' + str(error)
```

I have to ask for the status of the printer before he tries to `printLabel`, because if I can't ask for it he maybe gets in the "Resource busy" if clause inside the exception, prints the label, starts all over again and prints it again.

But if I could ask for the status I can say him something like:

```
def waitForPrinter(dev):
    dev = findPrinter()
    if dev.status() is True: ## True if he is ready and False if he is Busy or something
        printLabel(arguments and stuff)
    else:
        time.sleep(3)
        waitForPrinter()
```

I couldn't find a function in the documentation for asking the device status and don't know how to solve the problem right now.

At the moment i can only fetch the device status with the USBError.